# SignalR/Silverlight: Start must be called before data can be sent.

Tags: c#, silverlight, signalr

I have the following client code (Silverlight 4):

```
HubConnection hubConnection;
IHubProxy alertHub; 

hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:59805/");
alertHub = hubConnection.CreateProxy("alertservice");

Task startTask = hubConnection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {

    }

    alertHub.Invoke("NewMessage", "asdf", "jkl").Wait();
});
```

And the following server code (hosted in ASP.Net web project):

```
[HubName("alertservice")]
public class AlertServiceHub : Hub
{
    public void NewMessage(string userName, string messageText)
    {
        Clients.AddMessage(userName, messageText);
    }
}
```

On the `alertHub.Invoke` method, I get the error "Start must be called before data can be sent."

The strange thing is, when I check Fiddler on the connection attempt, the following is returned (note "Connection: Close"):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Tue, 14 Aug 2012 15:11:29 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Connection: Close
```

Comment: That looks like it should work just fine. Can you push a repro project somewhere and report the bug on github.

Comment: @dfowler - I found the problem - SignalR is using the System.Threading.Tasks port (http://robertmclaws.com/nuget-packages/system-threading-tasks-for-silverlight) but it is not compatible with the latest version 3.0.1. It was causing some strange things to happen. I found an old copy of 2.1.2 and it worked. Is it possible to take a look at this issue compatibility issue though?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue... using VS2010, Silverlight4, Nuget 2.1:

Used System.Threading.Tasks.SL4 2.1.2 as EkoostikMartin did, but same error.

at namespace Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http; HttpHelper class:

```
public static Task<HttpWebResponse> GetHttpResponseAsync(this HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                return Task.Factory.FromAsync<HttpWebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, ar => (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar), null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return TaskAsyncHelper.FromError<HttpWebResponse>(ex);
            }
        }
```

Error at: `(HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar)`

WebException:  I can see the request URL which seems right: localhost:12345/signalr/...